# algo to find number of common characters in 2 strings

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I am writing a c program to find the number of common characters in two strings.

> Eg: aabbccc      aabc     Ans:4
>
> ```
>    aabcA     aa       Ans:2
> ```

(Strings will have  upper case ,lower case and numbers)

I have two algorithms in my mind

Assuming length of strings is n,m

1.Sort the arrays and then count  O(nlogn+mlogm) complexity

2.scan through two strings and use a count arrays - O(n+m) complexity

Can anyone please suggest  further optimization or any other methods to do this?

Comment: @rullof i have written what algos i have in mind, i dont need any code .i just want to know whether it can be further optimized

Comment: @haccks yeah,i think it is a duplicate but i dint find my answer there.

Comment: [Set intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), basically.

Comment: @user3290349; Yes. Answer is there. You asked for other method too. That algorithm is of O(n).

Comment: @hackss my 2nd algo is O(n) complexity too!!

Comment: O(n) is the best you can do. How can you complete this task without at least read the string?

Answer (score 1):

basically you are asking about a **Bag(Multiset) Intersection**.

and I guess there won't be any more efficient algo than O(n+m) because you will have to go through each and every element of two bags at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Since, optimization is needed for big input, I think your second method is pretty fine(counting array method). Whatever algorithm you try to find out, you can't find the answer to your problem without looking at the two strings completely. Hence, there shouldn't be any further optimization to this problem as it is already O(m+n). I think for smaller input your first algorithm will work faster as there is a constant of O(26+26+10) associated with your second algorithm. But if you are really interested in a faster code then try to optimize the method of reading and writing the output. You may google for "faster I/O in  C++" and read about it.